# ASCII Println (New To Java)

Tags: java

```
        System.out.println(" _____       _            _       _");
        System.out.println("/  __ \     | |          | |     | |");
        System.out.println("| /  \/ __ _| | ___ _   _| | __ _| |_ ___  _ __");
        System.out.println("| |    / _` | |/ __| | | | |/ _` | __/ _ \| '__|");
        System.out.println("| \__/\ (_| | | (__| |_| | | (_| | || (_) | |");
        System.out.println(" \____/\__,_|_|\___|\__,_|_|\__,_|\__\___/|_|")
```

Need help wish outputting ASCII to add better design.
Error is "Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \ )"

Comment: \ is an escape character when used in a Java String, you need to use \\ if you want to print \

Answer (score 0):

replace every `\` with `\\` read about character escaping [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html)
 .